# Algolia working in local but not working on live server using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

currently i am working on laravel 5.5 and i am using alogia search. its working fine in locally when i search, add/update record but when i go to live server it is not working for add/update.
i am using vue search in my project.
this is my code :-

```
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;



 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        use Searchable;
        $data1 = $this->testrepo->findById($id);
        $data = $request->all();

        $data1->profile->update($data);
        $data1->update($data);
        return back();
    }
```

Comment: If someone read this later, we're also looking into this here: https://discourse.algolia.com/t/algolia-sync-is-not-working-on-production-server/5893/6